# Parabolic filtration of data in C

Tags: c, algorithm, filtering

I want to create a filtration of a value in order to prevent it from instant changes. I have a task which is executed on 20ms. The final aim is to create a filter which to receive time constant which to show what time should be elapsed to reach the aim value with parabolic change of the delta(data change step). For example to configure the filtration to reach value 10 with initial value of 0 for 8 seconds.

I have implemented PT1 filtration, but it has only decreasing delta changes(in the beginning the delta is bigger with big data change step and as close as it reaches the aim value the delta is getting smaller and smaller). The filtration that i want to reach is to have small delta in the beginning and in the end of the filtration time and biggest delta in the middle of the filtration time.

My question is if there is such an algorithm already? Or could you give me any advices how to handle the problem.

The target delta changes in time:

[image]

Comment: That [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iyee.png) doesn't look very parabolic to me.

Comment: it's simple paint example man :D

Comment: add image properly

Answer (score 0):

Your filtration rate f′(*t*) is a quadratic function with value 0 at time 0 and at time T (8 seconds) and the area under the curve between time 0 and time T is F (8 units). So the filtration rate function has the form:

> f′(*t*) = K·*t*·(T − *t*)

where the constant K is to be determined.  Expanding the above gives:

> f′(*t*) = K·T·*t* − K·*t*<sup>2</sup>

Integrating f′(*t*) with respect to *t* gives:

> ∫f′(*t*)·*dt* = (K·T/2)·*t*<sup>2</sup> − (K/3)·*t*<sup>3</sup> + c

F is the integral of f(*t*) from 0 to T with respect to *t*, so since the lower bound is 0, we can substitute T for *t* in the above and drop the constant of integration c, giving:

> F = (K·T/2)·T<sup>2</sup> − (K/3)·T<sup>3</sup>

which simplifies to:

> F = K·T<sup>3</sup>/6

Rearranging the above gives:

> K = 6·F/T<sup>3</sup>

So we can substitute that into the original f′(*t*), giving:

> f′(*t*) = (6·F/T<sup>3</sup>)·*t*·(T − *t*)

The above only applies for a continuous function f′(*t*), so you may need some minor adjustments because your real f′(*t*) only changes at 20 ms intervals. Taking the average between f′(*t*) and f′(*t* + .02) might be close enough. Another option is to use f'(*t*+.01) at each step. The most accurate option is to integrate from *t* to *t*+.02 at each step using the formula for the integral above and divide by .02.

For T = 8, F = 10, the filtration rate is given by:

> f′(*t*) = 0.1171075·*t*·(8 − *t*)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kinda hard to understand... but if you want an output that has has S-shaped response to a step change in the input, with the S-shape made from parabolic arcs, then it's very easy to do -- just apply a moving average filter twice.

In digital signal processing, this technique is common, and is known as a cascaded integrator-comb (CIC) filter.  You can google that and get lots of hits, but I'm afraid I couldn't find one suitable for someone with no DSP experience.   No matter -- it's just a simple moving average applied multiple times.

If you want the output to take 6 seconds to reach the final value after a step change in the input, then apply a 3-second moving average twice, or a 2-second moving average 3 times.  The latter will have a piecewise cubic shape instead of a parabolic shape, which you might like better.